# Mouse hover help tip and dynamic invalid credentials notification on a control's front

Tags: c#, hover

I'm a beginner in C# forms programming.
I have two questions

1. How do you show a help snippet as the user takes the mouse to a control and the snippet fades right away as the user takes the mouse away. I'm not sure what is this kind of control's technical name,either a hover over or what.

2.I don't want the user to know of the invalid login credentials when he presses the submit button. It should be dynamic,if the input in a text box is wrong,there's a lil red notification in front of the text box saying invalid input. Ofcourse it should be gone if the user inputs right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 you want a tooltip.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip(v=vs.71).aspx

For question 2, you should look up the key_press event of the textbox. ALthough if you are using this to dynamically update the user if the username/password combo is incorrect, it's not a very good idea.

If you're using it, for example, to validate a minimum number of characters required in a username then this is okay.